# Adapter is returning the same item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am using a ListView to display items in it, this is the layout of the cells:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/lon"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/foto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/lat"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textlon"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/foto"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textlat"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textlon"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Like every ListView, it needs an adapter:

```
public class FotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<BeanFotos> fotos;
private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
Context c;

public FotoAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<BeanFotos> fotos){
    this.fotos=fotos;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.c=c;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
//this returns the proper size of the array, if I have 3 photos it returns 3
    Log.i("David", "In adapter, the size of the array is: "+fotos.size());
    return fotos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
//this is never called
    Log.i("David", "returning item "+position);
    return fotos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        //This returns 0 always
        Log.i("David", "returning position "+position);
        int bmWidth=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getWidth();
        int bmHeight=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getHeight();
        int ivWidth;
        int ivHeigth;
        int new_width;
        int new_height;
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_layout, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.lat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlat);
        holder.lon=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlon);
        holder.foto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
        ivWidth=dpToPx(80);
        ivHeigth=dpToPx(80);
        new_width=ivWidth;
        new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bmHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) bmWidth));
        Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto(), new_width, new_height, true);
        holder.lat.setText(fotos.get(position).getLatitud().toString());
        holder.lon.setText(fotos.get(position).getLongitud().toString());

        holder.foto.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}

private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    float density = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float)dp * density);
}
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView lat;
    public TextView lon;
    public ImageView foto;
}
}
```

If i set a debug point where the photos are taken, I can see the different photographs I have taken, but in the ListView it displays the same photo (the first one). If I set a debug point in the adapter, the array that stores the object containing the photographs has the proper size, and the photographs stored are different...but the list view shows the same photograph always, despite it shows the proper number of rows.

Why is this happening? how can I fix it? Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Dear, Kindly add the code " ivWidth=dpToPx(80);
        ivHeigth=dpToPx(80);
        new_width=ivWidth;
        new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bmHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) bmWidth));
        Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto(), new_width, new_height, true);
        holder.lat.setText(fotos.get(position).getLatitud().toString());
        holder.lon.setText(fotos.get(position).getLongitud().toString());

        holder.foto.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);" before return view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
    //This returns 0 always

    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_layout, null);
    holder=new ViewHolder();
    holder.lat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlat);
    holder.lon=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlon);
    holder.foto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
int bmWidth=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getWidth();
int bmHeight=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getHeight();
int ivWidth;
int ivHeigth;
int new_width;
int new_height;
ivWidth=dpToPx(80);
ivHeigth=dpToPx(80);
new_width=ivWidth;
new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bmHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) bmWidth));
Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto(), new_width, new_height, true);
holder.lat.setText(fotos.get(position).getLatitud().toString());
holder.lon.setText(fotos.get(position).getLongitud().toString());
holder.foto.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: It's np, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

try to put list of below code outside the if else condition from if block,

```
    int bmWidth=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getWidth();
    int bmHeight=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getHeight();
    ivWidth=dpToPx(80);
    ivHeigth=dpToPx(80);
    new_width=ivWidth;
    new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bmHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) bmWidth));
    Bitmap newbitMap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto(), new_width, new_height,    true);
    holder.lat.setText(fotos.get(position).getLatitud().toString());
    holder.lon.setText(fotos.get(position).getLongitud().toString());

    holder.foto.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);
```

Comment: You were faster, but haint answer was more complete, so im accepting his. Thank you!